# Every method to set up automatic program start at login/startup?

Tags: windows-10, services, scheduled-tasks

I got a third-party program for which I turned off both scheduled tasks and services but the program still turns on at startup. OS: Windows 10. What other settings am I missing? I believe it is a legitimate program so I didn’t check if it hides other task/services under different names. There is also no shortcut in startup folder. Is there a 4th method to setup an automatic startup for programs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty... "official" and "unofficial" ones - simply speaking (the latter often used by adware etc.) various keys the registry is one example ([see here](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-program-automatic-startup-locations/)). I could put together a list but it would be quiet a lot of work. If you don't mind third party software [Scotty](http://winpatrol.com/download.html) give you an good overview...

Otherwise I would recommend to search for something like `auto startup locations windows` + `yoursoftware` until you find the appropriate one (assuming it doesn't try to "hide" itself).

Comment: Thank you. Counting the registry tricks and that private software, what percentage of methods do these covers in your opinion? Trying to get an overview of how many more methods there are left.